# Call decorator only once in a nested class function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

My class has the "public" functions attached with a decorator. In one of the functions, I call another class function that also has the same decorator. But given the decorator was already invoked, I'd like to skip this decorator call. Is there a way to achieve this?

Background: I have some virtual "circuit breakers" that I need to turn turn on/off between the calls. But if I call a function that already touched the circuit breakers once, then I'd want to avoid it in a nested call.

```
class foo:

    def my_decorator(func):

        @wraps(func)
        def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("before")
            val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print("after")
            return val
        return _wrapper

    @my_decorator
    def bar(self):
        return 0

    @my_decorator
    def baz(self):
        self.bar()
        return 1
```

In this example, I see :

```
f.baz()
before
before
after
after
```

How do I modify it so I only `before` and `after` once, like how bar does:

```
f.bar()
before
after
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problem you're trying to solve by implementing this decorator? It sound very likely that decorators are the wrong tool for the job. From what you've written here, your use case souds more like one for [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager).

Comment: I have some virtual "circuit breakers" that I need to turn turn on/off between the calls. But if I call a function that already touched the circuit breakers once, then I'd want to avoid it in a nested call.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. just don't decorate `bar`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then the before/after would be missing if `bar` gets called directly.

Comment: @KellyBundy sure, but my point is, then using a decorator here probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm open to using a different/better way for this. I started with decorators because I thought it would solve my problem. My actual function is a bit more involved and can return at different stages. So I used decorators instead.
Also, I need to decorate `bar`, because it can be invoked independently, not just part of `baz`

Comment: You are using a decorator to implement context management. Fine, that can work. You don't want to enter the context multiple times, right? Well, implement that logic in the decorator itself. Instead of trying not to "call" the decorator (too late for that, it was called when the function was created), modify its implementation so that nested calls don't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

> My class has the "public" functions attached with a decorator. In one
> of the functions, I call another class function that also has the same
> decorator. But given the decorator was already invoked, I'd like to
> skip this decorator call. Is there a way to achieve this?

So - first - keeping simple things simple: if this is a one-off situation, and you can hard-code inside `baz` that you want to call `bar` without the decorator, you can simply explicitly call the function given in its `__wrapped__` attribut, like in Karl's answer. The only objective drawback is that it won't work in conjunction with other decorators.

However, this approach involve knowing, and remembering, at development time, which other methods are decorated with the decorator we want to run only once, and write the inner code in accord to that. When working with decorators, the more standard practice is that once you add your decorator as a modifier to your function or method, you no longer have to worry about it - including not having to modify your code to cooperate with the decorator.

And then, is there a way for, inside the decorator code modify the decorated function so that the decorator will be skipped when another decorated method will be called?

No.
Not an feasible and sane way, nonetheless - to avoid the decorator to be entered at all could possibly only be done by modifying the bytecode in the decorated function, so that it could test when a call is to a sibling-decorated function and call the wrapped function instead.

But once the decorator is entered, testing for it becomes a bit easier - you then just refrain from re-running the code you don't want to run twice (or more times) -  this is not trivial, but it is for certain feasible in a reliable way.

For one thing, your decorator needs to share a state, so that it knows when it is "re-entering" and skip relevant code. One good way to share this might be through Python's context-vars: these are states that are unique to a thread or a task-callstack in async based code.

If however, your code might involve calling methods in other instances of the same object, and the decorator code needs to run once in each instance, you might need some more state keeping. I won't deal with this case in the proof of concept bellow.

So a first, verbose but safe, approach is this:

```
import contextvars

from functools import wraps

deco_state = contextvars.ContextVar("deco_state")

def my_decorator(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            deco_state.set(depth:=(deco_state.get(0) + 1))
            if depth <= 1:
                print("before")
            val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            if depth <= 1:
                print("after")
        finally:
            deco_state.set(deco_state.get() - 1)
        return val
    return _wrapper

class Foo:

    @my_decorator
    def bar(self):
        return 0

    @my_decorator
    def baz(self):
        self.bar()
        return 1

Foo().baz()
```

As stated: this will be resilient to multi-threaded and multi-async-task - but only if the different tasks are calling methods on the same instance. given this design, I suppose you want the decorator code to run once, and only once, in each instance of your `Foo` class, regardless of the method been called from different threads or different tasks in async code.

Then, instead of context-vars, one might just key the call counter to the instance.

Also, the example above is cumbersome, requiring two if statements and modifying the decorator code itself. We can take the need for rework this, and create a class that can decorate your wrapper (a decorator for the decorator), and be called in place of the `functools.wraps` decorator: it then can take the decision of running your wrapper or calling the decorated function directly.

So this class also performs the role of the outer-decorator code, the one which just annotates the `func` in a closure for the "wrapper" function, which is the real decorator.

Upon being called, the wrapper provided by this class will then know when to run the original function through your decorator, or go directly to the original function, and use contextvars.Context to check for recursivity.
Contextvars are a relatively new thing in Python, and they can track the "call stack" i.e. if one thread called "baz" in one context, another thread can call the same function in other contexts, and code inside those methods (or the decorator method), can see distinct values in the ContextVar instance. In this case we just need a boolean to know if the decorator has run in a given call-stack.

I took some time to make this production quality, as this code can also solve a problem I've met more than once: how to avoid a decorator to run twice, as you want, but when one *overrides* a decorated method in a subclass.

With this code, all one needs to do is to decorate both the method on the superclass and the overriden method in the child-classes with the same decorator.

All in all, this is the total code, with your example modified to run at the end:

```
from functools import wraps
from threading import RLock
import contextvars

RUNONCE = contextvars.ContextVar("RUNONCE", default=None)

class RunOnceDecorator:

    def __init__(self, decorator):
        self.decorator = decorator

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            v = RUNONCE.get()
            try:
                if v is None:
                    def mid():
                        # intermediary function needed to set a state on contextvars.context
                        nonlocal result
                        RUNONCE.set(True)
                        result = self.decorator(func,*args, **kwargs)
                    ctx = contextvars.Context()
                    ctx.run(mid)
                else:
                    ctx = None
                    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                del ctx
            return result
        return wrapper


# so, this is the thing: we can supress the outermost
# function, and get `func` as the very first
# parameter whenever it is called:

@RunOnceDecorator
def my_decorator(func, self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("before")
    val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    print("after")
    return val

class Foo:

    @my_decorator
    def bar(self):
        return 0

    @my_decorator
    def baz(self):
        self.bar()
        return 1

Foo().baz()
```

This will output simply:

```
$ python blip2.py 
before
after
```

There are no tests here, but it should work against multiple instances and multi-threading.

Comment: On the contrary, it's quite easy to access the original function, because a reference to it is kept around.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean in anyway that it is hard to reach the original function. That is trivial. What is hard is to skip entering the decorator code altogether: you have to enter it to make the check of whether to call the original function straight or run custom wrapper code.

Comment: I still don't see why. There isn't a check to make. When `bar` is called from `baz`, we should not enter the decorator code, so we can just hard-code to use the original function instead - as in my answer.

Comment: Your answer, while providing a plain, direct, ad-hoc way to do what the OP is asking for, and is therefore correct, bypasses  one of the main  idea of using decorators to start with, which is place a modifier to the function you once before its definition, and move with your life, with no changes needed in the function code. 
It is up to the OP to pick a "correct" answer which will work for him. And even them, keep in mind that other users come to the question facing the same issue - and yours direct answer may serve the OP, but not be enough for those other users, as not general enough.

Comment: there - I added a full example as it is a situation I had needed this behavior sometimes, but also added a pointer to your answer should it be enough.

Comment: (+1) Really like the way you answer questions by providing broad overview over various scenarios. Just want a confirmation from you: I think `ContextVar` is only useful when we run multiple threads or Tasks as it prevents them from overwriting values in concurrency(everyone has its own copy - "context"). Otherwise in the situation like your first code snippet, it can be replaced by a dictionary or even a single value(with `global` keyword). It's shared anyway right? Is there any advantage that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If this code is not multi-threaded  or concurrent in anyway, a dictionary would work. But contextvars.Context utility goes beyond that, and I found about it when thinking on this code: even in no async and no threaded code, one can _know_ which functions were called prior to the current one. And not mix things if the current function was called by another way. In other words, each task executed in code, by calling a function and that calling other functions, can share a private context invisible to other calls to the same functions.

Comment: This will usually only happen in concurrent code with asyncio or threading - but can take place in other unusual scenarios such as generators, or exception handling.

Answer (score 2):

When `functools.wraps` is used to decorate a wrapper function, it will attach the original function (that is being decorated by the wrapper) to the wrapper as its `__wrapped__` attribute. At the time the decorators are applied in the class, these are ordinary functions that belong to the class; and accessing it this way won't find it directly within the class, so it will still be a plain function and not a method. However, of course, we can just pass `self` explicitly to that.

Thus:

```
class foo:
    def my_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("before")
            val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print("after")
            return val
        return _wrapper
    @my_decorator
    def bar(self):
        return 0
    @my_decorator
    def baz(self):
        foo.bar.__wrapped__(self)
        return 1
```

Comment: There are many other metaprogramming techniques that could be used to get the same effect, but this is probably simplest. `foo.bar.__wrapped__(self)` and `self.bar.__wrapped__(self)` both work, but I think `foo.bar.__wrapped__(self)` is clearer - since the method-binding to the decorated `bar` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean member to the object, here `decorated` that gets flipped on the first time that `my_decorator` is called, and flipped off before that outermost call exits. You do enter the decorator function multiple times, but as long as you're more concerned with the decorator function only taking certain actions once (in this case printing) than you are with avoiding accidental recursion it should do.

```
from functools import wraps

class foo:
    decorated = False
    def my_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def _wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not self.decorated:
                print("before")
                self.decorated = True
                val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
                print("after")
                self.decorated = False
            else:
                val = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return val
        return _wrapper

    @my_decorator
    def bar(self):
        return 0

    @my_decorator
    def baz(self):
        self.bar()
        return 1
```

Per the comments this might be an "xy problem", but `foo.baz` will only print `before` and `after` once in this code.

Comment: Yeah you're right, this boolean is a simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do. I have clarified why exactly I need to do this, so maybe you have ideas to implement this in a better/elegant way.

Comment: l mean, if you've got a single threaded code and you only want to do something once, l don't think you get more elegant. (The call to `self.bar.__wrapped__` in Karl Knechtel's answer is probably a little better, but you _do_ have to keep track of what's the innermost function that's called in that case). If you've got multithreaded code and you only want to do the thing once l don't know what to tell you.